# Hadoop Cluster with HDFS High Availability

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, high-availability

Copy the HDFS Meta data from active name node to standby namenode.
    bin/hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby
    19/09/01 02:40:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    19/09/01 02:40:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-bootstrapStandby]
    19/09/01 02:40:39 WARN common.Util: Path /home/kenny/hadoop-2.7.3/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
    19/09/01 02:40:39 WARN common.Util: Path /home/kenny/hadoop-2.7.3/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
    19/09/01 02:40:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node-master-2/192.168.1.170:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
    19/09/01 02:40:42 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node-master-2/192.168.1.170:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCoun

Core-site setting
    core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ha-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
    <value>/home/kenny/hadoop-2.7.3/jn</value>
    </property>
```

hdfs-site setting
    hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/kenny/hadoop-2.7.3/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.permission</name>
    <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>ha-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.ha-cluster</name>
    <value>node-master,node-master-2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.node-master</name>
    <value>node-master:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.node-master-2</name>
    <value>node-master-2:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.node-master</name>
    <value>node-master:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.node-master-2</name>
    <value>node-master-2:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
    <value>qjournal://node-master:8485;node-master-2:8485;node1:8485/ha-cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.ha-cluster</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>node-master:2181,node-master-2:2181,node1:2181 </value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
    <value>sshfence</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
    <value>/home/kenny/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: I follow steps from edureka, any idea what is not configure correctly.
I have node-master, node-master-2 and node1. node-master should be namenode and node-master-2 should be the secondary name node. all 3 have journal node.
https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-set-up-hadoop-cluster-with-hdfs-high-availability/